# Mysql query return wrong result in left join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working with Codeigniter and MySQL. I have two table name as `information` and `review`.

Here I have attached image screenshot for my `information` table.

[image]

This is my `review` table

[image]

and this is my `info_img` table

[image]

Now, I want to get total no of `review` by `information id` as per `mytable`.

Here, I have written query like this :

```
SELECT 
    info.*,
    info_img.name AS image,
    COUNT(rev.review_id) AS total
FROM
    information AS info
        LEFT JOIN
    info_img ON info.information_id = info_img.information_id
        LEFT JOIN
    review AS rev ON rev.information_id = info.information_id
WHERE
    info.status = 1
        AND FIND_IN_SET('3', info.category)
GROUP BY rev.information_id
ORDER BY info.information_id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

I got 18 review count for `information_id = 8` that is wrong. Instead of it I want review count as 6 for `information_id = 8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you have to do is add distinct to your count.. :

```
select info.*,info_img.name as image,count(distinct rev.review_id) as total
from information as info
 left join info_img
   ON info.information_id = info_img.information_id 
 left join review as rev
   ON rev.information_id = info.information_id 
WHERE info.status =1
      AND FIND_IN_SET('3', info.category)
GROUP BY rev.information_id 
order by info.information_id Asc
LIMIT 0,3
```

The reason its happening is probably because information table is multiplying the results(by 3 as it seems) so each review_id will be counted 3 times, therefor - count distinct